# How to let Zimbra accept incoming mail only from some MXes and authenticated users?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, zimbra

I have a working Zimbra 8.0.6 OSE that is currently accepting mail from the outside to any of its locally defined domains and will also relay every mail from authenticated SMTP users.

There are other, external, MX servers that will receive, filter and then relay mail to Zimbra via SMTP: I'd like to configure Zimbra to not accept mail for local domains from everything but those MXes, and of course still accept and relay mail from any authenticated SMTP user. I went through the configuration, and documentation, and google, but did not find anything. I'm suspecting that Zimbra's configuration scheme / UI / whatever does not allow such a setup, but I would be glad if anyone could prove me wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply configure iptables to accept incoming connections to port 25 from specific IP addresses.

Comment: I would re-read the question and pay attention to *"any authenticated SMTP user"* :-)

Comment: relay and accept from are different things. besides, while standard smtp works over port 25, I always direct my users to 587 for SSMTP

Comment: That's true, but not accepting implies not relying, and accepting normal users is a requirement of this work and of the question. But thanks for trying :)